# Spring 3 complains about only one variable in the form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am processing a form in spring and it complaining about ONLY ONE variable in the form (it used to work before, not sure why it stopped working, there is no java code changes I made before and after it was working)

my object:

```
public class Store {

    private String implementation;

    private String name;

    private int replication;
    private String view;

    private List<String> remote;
    private List<String> clusters;

    private String cluster;
    private String type;

    // getters and setters
}
```

my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/aaaaa", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("implementations", implData);
    model.addObject("store", new Store());
    model.setViewName("nameOfView");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/aaaaa", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processAddition(@ModelAttribute("store") Store store) {
   // some processing
}
```

my JSP form:

```
<form:form id="form" name="form" method="post" modelAttribute="store" action="/zzzzz">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input select">
        <label for="implementation" >Implementation<span class="small">Choose implementation</span></label>
        <form:select name="implementation" path="implementation">
            <form:option value="">Choose Implementation</form:option>
            <c:forEach items="${implementations.keySet()}" var="impl">
                        <form:option value="${impl}"><c:out value="${impl}" /></form:option>
            </c:forEach>
         </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="input select">
        <form:select id="cluster" name="cluster" path="cluster">
                <form:option value="">Choose Cluster</form:option>
        <c:forEach items="${implementations.get('aaaa').getClusters().keySet()}" var="cl">                              
                    <form:option value="${cl}"><c:out value="${cl}" /></form:option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
            <form:select id="type" name="type" path="type">
        <form:option value="">Cluster Type</form:option>
        <form:option value="new">New</form:option>
        <form:option value="old">Old</form:option>
        </form:select>
        <div style="display: none;" id="remote">
            <label>Remote Sites <span class="small">Available Remote Sites</span></label>
                <form:checkbox path="remote" id="remote" name="remote" value="" />
            <div id="append">
         **I am appending the "form:checkbox for remote dynamically here using javascript and for spring not to complain I added a empty checkbox on top, still it complains**                              
            </div>
            </div>
           <input style="margin-left: 150px; width: 125px; height: 30px;" class="button" type="submit" value="Add" />
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'remote' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:78)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:82)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag.writeTagContent(CheckboxTag.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
```

any help ?

Thanks

Comment: This is only a hint for an try (because I observed once a verz stange behavior) - Replace the List by an Set.

Comment: I did try it just now, no luck

Comment: If the problem still exits, then please "capture" the HTTP request that submit the values, and add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "remote" object in your request/model.  You need to add it, but a list for checkbox will not work either.

Comment: I do have "List<String> remote" in my Store model

Comment: I am not sure why all the variables are NOT complaining, its just that one variable in my model, that's weird.

Comment: checkbox will expect one value not list of values that probably is the reason. Do you need several checkboxes? Why remote is a list?

Comment: remote has lots of remote sites, I meant form:checkboxes.

Comment: Then, a for loop may be better